# SQL - Modeling Roles For Employees

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, modeling

I am wondering how best to represent the following situation in the database.

You have a table for roles. There are only a few: [MANAGER, STOCK, CASHIER, DEFAULT].
There is a many to many relationship between employee and store. 
A store can have many employees and an employee can be employed at many stores. In addition, an employee can only have one role per store that he/she is associated with.

If the below the correct way to model these tables? Is there a better way?

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeStore
(
    Id 
    StoreId
    EmployeeId
    EmployeeRoleId 
)

CREATE TABLE Store
(
    Id 
    Name
)

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Id 
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE Role
(
    Id 
    ...
)
```

Comment: If an employee can have only 1 role per store, then there could be a unique constraint or primary key on (StoreId, EmployeeId) in EmployeeStore.

Comment: And if you want to use a USING clause in your queries, then perhaps rename those `id` fields to the same name as those foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when there is many-to-many relationship, keep in mind that you have to create a new  table for that 'many-to-many' relation, the primary keys of both tables work as foreign keys there, and the combination of these two work as a primary key in the new table. Let me clear it with an example:

Let suppose we have a table `STUDENTS` having different attributes like `student_id(pk), Student_name` etc and there is a second table named as `subject` having different attributes like `subjectCode(pk), subject_faculty, subject_duration` etc

The relation between these two tables is many-to-many, as one student can register more than one subjects and a subject can have many students, for this situation we make a new third table `StudentsSubject` having `student_id` and `subjectCode` as foreign keys from the existing tables, and the combination of these two attributes act as the primary key of this table,  you may study it for more details.